# How to read in SqlLite field which has the date Format?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime

How do I read in DateTime Field from SqlLite Db? I am getting the below error:

```
System.FormatException: 'String '01.06.2001 00:00' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

The Method which I am using is as per below. I can see in debug mode, that other fields are being read in, though once it comes to the DateTime field it fails.

```
public static SingleTable QueryDbTable(string sqlSelect)
    {
        var result = new SingleTable();
        var fileUrl = @"URI=file:C:Url\Database\DB.db";

        using var con = new SQLiteConnection(fileUrl); con.Open();
        using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sqlSelect, con);
        using SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        var cols = dr.FieldCount;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var singleRow = new SingleRow();

            for (var i = 6; i < cols; i++)
            {
                if (!dr.IsDBNull(i))
                {
                    singleRow.Col.Add(dr.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    continue;
                }

                singleRow.Col.Add("");
            }

            result.Table.Add(singleRow);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The linked classes:

```
public class SingleTable
{
    public List<SingleRow> Table { get; set; } = new List<SingleRow>();
}

public class SingleRow
{
    public List<string> Col { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

The goal is just to read in the Fields in the system as a table.

I have tried as well to save it in various ways to a variable (mostly foolish tries), but it gives the same error.

```
var item = dr.GetDateTime(i);
```

Though these are the basics, I couldn't find where it could explain how to read the data in, but how to select, or insert only.

Any suggestions, how can I store the DateTime element in a variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading an SQLite DateTime value from database and assigning it to a C# string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42630427/reading-an-sqlite-datetime-value-from-database-and-assigning-it-to-a-c-sharp-str)

Comment: No, tried it already. Meaning, parse to `DateTime.Parse(readList["dob"].ToString())` it cannot be read in an item overall. in any way. Just in a variable. seems like there is something simple which I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I still not sure why, but the workaround is to do this, basically, Manually Parsing, while anything for the reader did not work, could not directly parse the dr.GetString(i), or anything like that.

```
   try
        {
            validFrom = (DateTime) dr["ValidFrom"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var i = dr.GetOrdinal("ValidFrom");
            var stringValidFrom = dr.GetString(i);
            var parsedSuccesfully = DateTime.TryParse(stringValidFrom, out var value);
            validFrom = value;
        }
```

Maybe someone will know why, but this is how I ended up getting the result.